# Filtering data from elastic search based on mongodb

Tags: database-design, mongodb, elasticsearch

I've a list of items in my ElasticSearch.
User enters a query and I fetch the results from elastic search. Now, I've a requirement where I don't want to show the user the items which he has already visited. The items which user has already visited is stored in mongodb.
`id, user_id, item_id`

I choose this MongoDB schema because a user could have a very big list of items(I'm expecting an entry of 300 items daily per user).

I came up with a solution

1. Suppose, I want to return approx. 10 results in one api call based on the query.
2. I fetch 30 items from the elasticsearch.
3. I check how many of those are present in the mongodb and remove them from the results.

This doesn't guarantee the number of results which will be returned in the api. It could be 0 also.

Is there any better way to do this? Maybe some different schema or technology stack.

Comment: Just a clarification. I'm expecting 300 entries daily per user.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional information, rather than putting that in a comment.